# Algorithm for searching the shortest length between words

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm for finding the shortest distance between a list of words.  I have a dictionary of lists that shows different locations in a document a word is found.

matches{"the" : [2, 24, 15], "is" : [5, 13], "apple" : {45} ... }

Are there established algorithms for finding the shortest length where all of these overlap?  For example, in this one 13-45 would be the answer because all of the words can be found in that range.

Comment: google A*, it can be used for words amongst other things

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep two positions, `left` and `right` which are, respectively, the left and right ends of a range that contains all the words. I'd also maintain a priority queue, each entry of which is a word and the list of places the word occurs at or after the current left edge.

To initialize, make a new empty priority queue, insert each word with it's full list of occurrences, properly sorted. As you insert each word, update `right` so it's the maximum first occurrence of any word. For your data, the initial setup would be

```
left=2,right=45,queue=[["the", [2,15,24]], ["is", [5, 13], ["apple", [45]]
```

I'm showing the priority queue as if it were an array, sorted by the first component of its second component. That is, in the order 2 (for "the"), 5 (for "is"), and 45 (for "apple"). Note that the occurrences for "the" had to be sorted during this initialization. `right` turns out to be 45, the maximum of 2, 5, and 45.

`left` is implicit. It's always the first occurrence of whatever's at the front of the priority queue. At this point the shortest range we've found is 2..45.

Then repeat the following loop:

```
remove the first entry from the priority queue
shift its next occurrence into `left`
check if left..right is a new shortest sequence
if we've shifted off the last occurrence for this entry
    stop
otherwise, 
    update `right` to include this new next occurrence
    insert the entry back into the priority queue
```

With your data, the successive values would be:

```
left=2,right=45,queue=[["the", [2,15,24]], ["is", [5, 13], ["apple", [45]]
left=5,right=45,queue=[["is", [5, 13], ["the", [15,24]], ["apple", [45]]
left=13,right=45,queue=[["is", [13], ["the", [15,24]], ["apple", [45]]
```

and we terminate, because after popping `["is", [13]]` from the queue and shifting 13 off its list of occurrences, none remain.